# The point of LEA?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel

If I have:

```
lea     eax, [ebp-20]
push    eax
```

Can I not just write it as:

```
mov     eax, ebp-20
push    eax
```

Why is the first one preferred over the second?

Comment: `mov     eax, ebp-20` isn't valid in NASM syntax and ins't an encodable instruction.

Comment: It's common for people coming from higher-level languages to want to write assembly code like `mov eax, 7*ebx+(edx/9)+(eax*edi)-27`.  But you can't write arbitrary algebraic expressions, except for constants; each step of that evaluation requires a separate instruction to be executed, and you have to code each of them individually.

Comment: *Can I not just write it as:*  You could have answered that with a "no" yourself, just by trying it.  Then with some more searching, you'd find out why not.  There are no forms of `mov` that can do math on the value being copied to the destination.  Also, if `mov` worked, the obvious optimization would be `push ebx-20`, not wasting an instruction.

Comment: BTW, "why doesn't / can't `mov eax, ebp-20` work" could be a reasonable CPU / language-design question.  You could [edit] this to not assume a false premise.  Part of the answer to *that* is that assembly is not a *compiled* language; every asm line has to map to one machine instruction, encoded in machine code.  (Like Nate said).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 languages - assembly language, and machine code.

There is no reason why you can't invent your own assembly language that generates the same machine code; where the plain text `"mov eax,ebp - 20"` is supported (and converted into the same machine code as a `lea eax,[ebp-20]` would have generated in other assemblers).

There are 2 reasons why assemblers don't do this:

a) Conventions. It's nice if all assemblers use the same mnemonics for the same things, and if those mnemonics are used by CPU manuals; because this makes it easier to learn assembly language and easier to switch from one assembler to another.

b) Parsing. An assembler ends up having to parse text like `"mov eax,[ebp-20]"` and it's easier to recycle the same parsing code to handle `"lea eax,[ebp-20]"` and avoid having different code to parse an additional operand format.

Note: There's also a plausible reason for wanting to an assembler to do this. Often `lea` is used for integer arithmetic that has nothing to do with effective address calculations; and supporting an alternative `mov` syntax would give programmers a way to add context and improve code readability (e.g. use `lea` when it is an address and use `mov` when it's not an address so it's easier to tell what is/isn't intended to be an address).